# Estruturar dados vindos do DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Olá amigos desenvolvedores,

tenho uma consulta que traz áreas geográficas que estejam contidas em unidades maiores de área; estas unidades maiores são recebidas via params (id) e podem ser uma ou mais, sem limitação.

PS. Antes dos cálculos geográficos eu busco pelos polígonos que representam estas unidades (pelo id recebido)

Importante dizer que para cada unidade recebida é gerado um filtro usando sequelize.where e sequelize.fn que depois é injetado na consulta:

**MOMENTO DE CRIAÇÃO DO FILTRO:**

```
if (query.length > 1) { 
    polygons.map(p => intersectionUnitsFilter.push(this.intersectsUnits(p.coordinates, p.type)));
```

**FUNÇÃO QUE CRIA EFETIVAMENTE O FILTRO (IntersectUnits):**

```
intersectsUnits(encoded: string, type: string) { // mudar esse encoded
    const coords: any = encoded
    
    let wkt = wktParser.convert({
      type: type,
      coordinates: coords,
    });
    
    const polygon = Sequelize.fn('ST_GeomFromText', wkt, 4326);
    const intersects = Sequelize.fn('ST_Intersects', Sequelize.fn('ST_SetSRID', Sequelize.col('polygon'), 4326), polygon);
    const intersectionFilter = Sequelize.where(intersects, true); // maybe i can add some code here to change the query and add some column

    return intersectionFilter;
  }
```

Apenas para contextualizar tudo isto, este é o momento da consulta final => O código que insere o filtro gerado a partir de unidades é injetado na variável filters que é usada dentro da query final:

```
filters = { 
            ...filters,
            [Op.and]: {
              [Op.or]: {
                ...intersectionUnitsFilter
              }
            }
          }
        }
        
      }

      if (subfilters.length) {
        filters = {
          ...filters,
          [Op.or]: subfilters
        }
      }

      const limit = params.limit ? params.limit : 1000;
      let areas = await Area.findAll({
        where: filters,
        include: relationships,
        offset: params.page ? params.page * limit : 0, 
        limit: limit
      });

      return areas;
```

**O PROBLEMA:**

Se eu recebo mais de 1 unidade, todas as áreas filtradas vem misturadas, não há nenhuma distinção sobre o filtro que foi aplicado numa área específica, ou seja, eu não saberia dizer a qual unidade pertence uma determinada área, eu só sei dizer que todos os resultados estão contidos numa área ou outra e isto dificulta algumas condições lá no frontend.

**TENTATIVAS DE SOLUÇÃO:**

1 - Primeiro tentei iterar pelos filtros e para cada filtro setar uma variável filter e injetar na query. Desta forma eu faria queries separadamente, recebendo para cada iteração um array com áreas pertencentes a UMA unidade apenas. Eu poderia por exemplo aplicar um `Object.assign` e construir objetos identificando a qual unidade pertence aquele array. Tive dificuldades pois o await não funcionar dentro de callbacks e fiquei confuso para fazer uma Promise que fosse um wrapper para toda a consulta.

2 - Procurei insistentemente por comandos sequelize e tipos de queries que pudessem fazer esse trabalho direto no banco de dados, sem sucesso.

Existe uma solução fácil e rápida para o problema?